# Export R object for 3D printing

Tags: r, 3d, export

If I have a data set in R, what would be a good way to export it so I could get it to a service like Shapeways for 3D printing?

I don't have any "real" CAD software, but I've used Google Sketchup before.

In my case the object can be described by two surface plots, something like this:

```
x <- y <- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
persp(x, y, outer(x, y, function(x,y) (x+y)^2))
persp(x, y, outer(x, y, function(x,y) rep(0,length(x))), zlim=c(-1,1))
```

...which I would like to appear together as one object to be printed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shapeways says it can take output from MeshLab: http://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/files/meshlab

MeshLab, an open-source, free-as-in-beer project,  is able to import this file using its `.asc` format option:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=x,   # will be recycled 101 times
                  y=rep(y, each=101),
                  z=as.vector(outer(x, y, function(x,y) (x+y)^2)))

write.table(dat, file="out.asc", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

I probably should have done an sos-search;

```
library(sos)
findFn("3d printing")
```

.... did bring up the `r2stl` package whose sole function has the same name. It also found other convex hull functions that might be useful to others that want to build other 3D shapes from data.

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  I also found the `r2stl` package that generates `.stl` files, which can also be imported into MeshLab.

Comment: Indeed. `r2stl`'s help page specifically suggests MeshLab.

Comment: One difference between the two approaches - your approach loads into MeshLab as a surface, which is what I want.  `r2stl` loads as a solid object, with all the space filled in below.

Comment: You may need to "extrude" the surface along a z-direction. At the moment, the thickness is zero.

Comment: Indeed - when I upload to Shapeways, the zero-thickness parts of the model don't show up.  I brought it in to Sketchup as a `.dae` file (COLLADA) but the Push/Pull tool refuses to operate on it.

Answer (score 5):

DWin has already made one suggestion for the mesh. If you need to export the resulting object from Meshlab and manipulate it in an extraordinarily intuitive 3D application that doesn't cost the earth then you should try [MoI 3D](http://moi3d.com).

I mention this because MoI has a very competent mesh engine and many of MoI's users seem to be involved in 3D printing (see for example [this](http://moi3d.com/forum/messages.php?webtag=MOI&msg=6270.1) thread).

The developer Michael Gibson often responds to forum questions in, literally, minutes and other users in the forum are very supportive. There is a full 30-day trial version that allows you to experiment at no cost. MoI can also be scripted using JavaScript.

By its nature 3D printing is irrevocably real so it pays to be sure before you commit!

Comment: It could work for this one time, but I'm afraid MoI is still priced out of my league.  I'm just making little trinkets for fun.